# Why does the absolute legal owner of property also have a beneficial interest in it, without any equitable interest?

Tags: england-and-wales, equity

Why does the absolute legal owner of property also have a beneficial interest in it? Because the author's distinguishing "beneficial" from "equitable", then what does the author mean by "beneficial" here?

> Judges and commentators have often used the word ‘beneficial’ followed by ‘rights’,
> ‘interest’, or ‘ownership’. This is a particular source of confusion. Sometimes, a beneficial
> interest is simply a different way of describing an equitable interest in property. But **‘beneficial’
> does not always correspond with ‘equitable’, because the absolute legal owner of
> property also has a beneficial interest in it without any equitable interest.** ‘Beneficial interest’
> is therefore best used descriptively to identify a person’s right to receive some or all of
> the benefit of property, such as the use of the property or its fruits. So, ***if the legal owner of
> property has absolute title to the property, they will also have the beneficial interest in the
> property.*** But if the legal owner holds that property on trust for another, that other person
> will have the beneficial interest in the property as well as an equitable proprietary interest
> in it. It is also possible for the legal owner of property to hold that property on trust for
> themself and another person, in which case both the legal owner and the other beneficiary
> will have beneficial interests in the property.

Virgo, *The Principles of Equity & Trusts* 2020 4 edn. Page 46.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the absolute legal owner of property also have a beneficial
> interest in it?

Because the owner of property in which no one else has an interest is entitled to the benefits of ownership.

> Because the author's distinguishing "beneficial" from "equitable",
> then what does the author mean by "beneficial" here?

Beneficial means the right to gain personal economic benefit from property.

An example would be a trustee for Fred who owns a mutual fund, which is a business trust that has legal ownership of lots of securities (or perhaps street name ownership in those securities through a nominee). Holders of mutual fund shares have an equitable ownership in these securities. But because the equitable ownership is held for the benefit of Fred, the Trustee does not have a beneficial ownership in the securities owned directly or indirectly by the mutual fund.

Answer (score 1):

**Beneficial** is related to **benefit**. If you are the absolute legal owner of land (for example) then you have the benefit of it - you can use it how you like for your own benefit.

If you do not have legal title (say it is held on a bare trust for you by trustee T) but you are, nevertheless, the owner in equity — then again you have the benefit of it, so you are the beneficial owner.

T is the legal owner but they are not the beneficial owner — T is obliged to carry out their duties as trustee, and can't use the land for their own benefit.

Virgo is using the word **equitable** in a more restrictive sense than most lawyers do (as he freely acknowledges) and that is another story. But he is using the word  **beneficial** in the same sense as lawyers generally do.